# Display time with 1 zero when seconds is less or equal to 60 seconds

Tags: php, datetime

I'm displaying videos and I want to show the duration. Im using the following:

```
echo ltrim(date('i:s', $vduration), '0')

//result
5:40
```

But, if the video is 40 seconds only. The formula doesn't work. It shows

```
:40
```

Basically, if the video is less then 60 seconds, it should show 1 zero only (not 2), like so:

```
0:40
```

Is there a magic formula for this or do I need to use conditions to check if less or equal to 60 seconds?

Comment: Do you know what the `ltrim` is doing? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: @Alan I think he knows why this doesn't work, the question is how to do what he wants.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry.  I would replace the `ltrim` with a `str_replace` to replace '00:' with '0:', i.e. `str_replace( '00:', '0:', date('i:s', $vduration) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `date()`, use `printf()` to format the numbers the way you wan.

```
$minutes = date('i', $vduration);
$seconds = date('s', $vduration);
printf("%d:%02d", $minutes, $seconds);
```

`%d` will format a number with no leading zeroes, `%02d` will format a number in 2 digits with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

A date is poorly suited to represent a time interval. The DateInterval class is better suited. The [date interval format method](https://www.php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php) can also represent minutes without leading zeros.

```
//example to create a date interval
$timeStart = date_create_from_format('!','');
$timeEnd = date_create_from_format('!i:s','00:07');

$interval = $timeStart->diff($timeEnd);

//output
echo $interval->format('%i:%S');  //0:07
```

If the minutes and seconds are given, a date interval can also be created directly.

```
$minute= 1;
$second = 40;
$interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$minute.'M'.$second.'S');
```